# Centrar imagen (logo) y texto en linea (navegación)

Tags: html, css

Quiero poner una imagen `.png` que seria mi logo  y el menu de navegacion a lado de este, pero no logro centrar el texto y la imagen, ¿Alguien puede ayudarme? Gracias.

tengo los contenedores y todo
quiero alinear el `logo` y el `nav` y que queden un poco mas junto las dos cosas, estoy usando `grid`, como le puedo hacer

```css
    html {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-size: 62.5%;
    }
    
    *,
    *:before,
    *:after {
        box-sizing: inherit;
    }
    
    body {
        font-size: 1.6rem;
        line-height: 2;
        background-image: url("../img/35.jpg");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
    }
    
    .contenedor {
        max-width: 1200px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    img {
        max-width: 100%;
    }
    
    .centrar-texto {
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    .productos a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
        font-size: 2.5rem;
        font-family: 'Public Sans';
        margin-left: 2rem;
    }
    
    .logo {
        width: 40rem;
        height: 40rem;
        margin: 0;
        height: 100px;
    }
    
    .navegacion {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
        align-items: center;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/normalize.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700|Public+Sans:400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Raspados Isla</title>
</head>

<body>

    <header class="barra-nav ">
        <main class="navegacion centrar-texto">
            <a href="#" class="logo">
                <img src="/img/logoo.png" alt="Logo">
            </a>
            <nav class="productos">
                <a href="raspados.html">Raspados</a>
                <a href="tejuino.html">Tejuino</a>
                <a href="tuba.html">Tuba</a>
                <a href="tepache.html">Tepache</a>
                <a href="cerveza-raiz.html">Cerveza de Raíz</a>
            </nav>
        </main>

    </header>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

La solución mas rapida seria meter la imagen dentro de la class de productos, aunque no es la mas adecuada, te dejo el ejemplo:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/normalize.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700|Public+Sans:400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Raspados Isla</title>
</head>

<body>

    <header class="barra-nav ">
        <main class="navegacion centrar-texto">
            <nav class="productos">
              <a href="#" class="logo">
                <img src="/img/logoo.png" alt="Logo">
            </a>
                <a href="raspados.html">Raspados</a>
                <a href="tejuino.html">Tejuino</a>
                <a href="tuba.html">Tuba</a>
                <a href="tepache.html">Tepache</a>
                <a href="cerveza-raiz.html">Cerveza de Raíz</a>
            </nav>
        </main>

    </header>

</body>

</html>
```

Otra solución seria en el css modificar los parámetros de la class logo.Te dejo este pequeño resumen, espero que te ayude! Un saludo :)
http://joaquin.medina.name/web2008/documentos/informatica/lenguajes/HTML/CSS/2010_08_21_CSS_CentrarImagen.html

Comment: Gracias! Lo voy a intentar

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre que lo hagas de este modo:

- Tanto tu imagen como tu menú envuélvelos dentro de un contenedor principal, por ejemplo un `div`
- A ese contenedor le indicas que se dividirá en 2 y tendrá un display `grid`
- Al contenedor que engloba el menú le indicas un ancho mínimo de 80% sobre el viewport
- Al contenedor del menú le indicamos que tenga un `display: flex;`
- Con `flex-grow` a 1 indicamos cuanto debe crecer cada elemento del menú
- **Sólo coloca el enlace a una imagen válida donde yo dejo la tag `img` vacía por ejemplo de 30*30px** para que notes el efecto

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>Ejemplo</title>
      <style>
        .menu-principal {
          display: grid;
          grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);      
        }
        .menu {
          display: flex;
          background-color: black;
          list-style: none; 
          padding: 0;
          text-align: center;  
          min-width: 80vw;
        }
        
        .elementos {
          flex-grow: 1;
          color: white;     
        }
    
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="menu-principal">
      <img src="rutaatuimagen" alt="">
        <ul class="menu">
          <li class="elementos">1</li>
          <li class="elementos">2</li>
          <li class="elementos">3</li>
          <li class="elementos">4</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Si es bueno mezclar flexbox con grid? Y puedes recomendarme algun  articulo o libro para aprender mas sobre el tema? Gracias.

Comment: Ya puse las nuevas lineas, pero el texto y la imagen siguen sin alinearse completamente ¿Como puedo alinear eso bien? Gracias por la ayuda!